# Facebook app development environment on localhost

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am running an app live at `domain.com` and wants to continue the development on localhost for which I setup `local.domain.com` to `127.0.0.1` in my hosts file. Everything works fine other than PHP is not able to pick up session when the login is handled by the JS SDK.

My JS code:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            if (response.perms) {
                // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
                // perms is a comma separated list of granted permissions
                init();
            } else {
                // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions, eh?
                showMessage( "Error!", "You haven't grant proper permissions!" );
            }
        } else {
            // user is not logged in
            showMessage( "Error!", "You are not logged in" );
        }
    }, {perms:'email'});
```

After the login from JS, I do an AJAX call where PHP can't pick up session information.
My PHP code:

`$session = $facebook->getSession(); // this is null somehow`

The same code works fine, live on `domain.com` but on localhost, the `$session` on PHP side 
is null. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `localhost` as your application domain name?

You should probably create 2 apps, one for your local testing and another one for your live code.

Comment: That should work in the normal case just like my method is working but since the app is working fine on the front end, there is something else going on here. And moreover my app is live and I need the current users of the app in development too. Any idea what can I try here?